# My app.js is not able to read my index.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I've included my index.js file in an external folder and I've used jQuery in it. But when I try to run my app.js I get an error. Below I've posted details of my code and error.

here is my code for app.js:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const https = require('https');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const jquery = require('jquery');
    
    const app=express();
    app.use('/jquery', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/'));
    const inputs=require(__dirname+'\\public\\js\\index')
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    app.get("/",function(req, res){
        res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
    });
    app.listen(5000, function(){
        console.log("The server is started on port 5000");
    });
```

Here is my folder structure

[image: Folder Structure]

And here is the error I get when I try to run my app.js

[image: Error]

Comment: The main problem is that NodeJS does not know `$` as a function.
What is the overall objective, is it your intend to use jQuery (mostly frontend purposes) on the backend?

Comment: Remove `const inputs=require(__dirname+'\\public\\js\\index')`

Comment: @Palladium02 I have my index.js for dom manipulation and I've also figured out a way to take inputs by writing some logic using jQuery in index.js in hopes of getting input data which I will be finally using to build a url string through which I'll be requesting data from the api

Comment: @LawrenceCherone why should I remove? it has my whole logic from dom manipulation to getting inputs